# Solve of cubic and quartic equations too slow

Tags: equation-solving, series-expansion

In my problem I have a third order algebraic equation for the variable `sigma`, all other letters are parameters. Here is  it's right-hand side, left hand side is zero (you can copy it into your programm):

```
eq = Er k^2 γ ξ (1 + λ Cos[2 ϕ]) (3 I k Cos[ϕ] + 4 σ Cos[2 ϕ] + 
    I k Cos[3 ϕ]) Subscript[α, ac] + (ξ + σ) (σ + I k Cos[ϕ]) (8 k^4 + 
    16 k^2 tf1 + 2 k^4 γ + k^4 γ λ^2 + 8 Er k^2 γ σ + 16 Er tf1 γ σ + 
    4 k^4 γ λ Cos[2 ϕ] + k^4 γ λ^2 Cos[4 ϕ] + 
    4 k^2 (k^2 + Er γ σ) Sin[2 ϕ]^2 Subscript[μ, 1] + 
    4 (k^2 + Er γ σ) (k^2 + tf1 - tf1 Cos[2 ϕ]) Subscript[μ, 2])
```

My purpose here is to get Taylor expansion in parameter `k` for all the roots near `k=0`:

```
sol = Solve[eq == 0, σ]
sol = σ /. sol
Series[sol[[1]], {k, 0, 2}
```

The thing is, that evalution of the line `sol = Solve[eq == 0, σ]` takes really long time. It takes couple minutes here, but when I am trying to solve similar equation of the 4th order, it takes forever. Note, that in the line `sol = Solve[eq == 0, σ]`, I didn't ask to simplify. But looks like mathematica silently simplifies it, since it is running for a long time. Note, that for the third and forth order equations exact algebraic expressions for the solutions are availible, and indeed, if I type something like `Solve[a*x^3+b*x^2+c*x+d==0,x]`, it gives me the answer instantly. It should be really fast procedure to substitute corresponding expressions into the final formula.

Is there a way to get Taylor expansion I need faster? Solving the equations takes much longer time, than Taylor series.

In case someone needs, this is the 4th order equation, which I cannot solve  even in 30 minutes:

```
-Er k^2 γ ξ (1 + λ Cos[2 ϕ]) (4 (k^2 + 2 σ (σ + τ1)) Cos[2 ϕ] + k^2 (3 + Cos[4 ϕ]))
    Subscript[α, ac] - (ξ + σ) (k^2 + 2 σ (σ + τ1) + k^2 Cos[2 ϕ]) (8 k^4 + 16 k^2 tf1 + 
    2 k^4 γ + k^4 γ λ^2 + 8 Er k^2 γ σ + 16 Er tf1 γ σ + 4 k^4 γ λ Cos[2 ϕ] + 
    k^4 γ λ^2 Cos[4 ϕ] + 4 k^2 (k^2 + Er γ σ) Sin[2 ϕ]^2 Subscript[μ, 1] + 
    4 (k^2 + Er γ σ) (k^2 + tf1 - tf1 Cos[2 ϕ]) Subscript[μ, 2])
```

Evaluation of `sol = Solve[eq == 0,σ]` takes forever.

I found out, that `Defer` can be used to supress evalution, but I need a different thing.

Thanks,
MIkhail

Comment: I find that `sol = Solve[eq == 0, σ]` takes just seconds, although the result is rather large.  By the way, avoid using `Subscript`.

Comment: Furthermore, solving the fourth order equation takes only a minute or so.  How much memory do you have on your computer?

Comment: `sol = Solve[eq == 0, σ]` took 2 minutes on my computer. The method I presented below takes around 3 seconds.

Comment: bbgodfrey, what PC do you have? I have laptop with 8GB RAM, quadcore intel i7. Using device manager I found out, that during the calculations ~20% of CPU and ~40% of RAM is used, so I doubt, that the issue is in memory. Thanks for the edit, btw

Comment: @MikhailGenkin  I have an essentially identical computer running 10.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (October 9, 2015).  The calculations complete so quickly that I cannot accurately determine CPU and memory usage with Task Manager for the cubic case.  The quartic case takes less than a minute with 17% CPU usage and about 200 MB memory usage.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, what version of Mathematica do you have? My is 10.0.1.0. I think, I know what's going on. My Mathematica is trying to solve the equation, first simplifying it, etc..., whether your version is using the formula for 3rd order algebraic equation, substituting the parameters afterwards. I can force my Mathematica to do it by using method described by @JHM: first to create coefficient list, solve `ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0`, and then substitute parameters from coefficient list instead of `a,b,c,d`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey So I think that's why we have different results. Thanks for the discussion.

Comment: @bbgodfrey How can you copy a piece of code from Mathematica to StackOverflow to preserve greek letters? I use `StandartForm`  and copy it with my mouse. But as you have seen, the result doesn't look good. Or the only solution is to correct everything manually?

Comment: @MikhailGenkin  See the comments to [Meta Mathematica 1553](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1553/differentiald-not-displayed-correctly-in-mathematica-stackexchange).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a workaround:

```
eq = Er k^2 γ ξ (1 + λ Cos[2 ϕ]) (3 I k Cos[ϕ] + 4 σ Cos[2 ϕ] + 
    I k Cos[3 ϕ]) Subscript[α, ac] + (ξ + σ) (σ + I k Cos[ϕ]) (8 k^4 + 
    16 k^2 tf1 + 2 k^4 γ + k^4 γ λ^2 + 8 Er k^2 γ σ + 16 Er tf1 γ σ + 
    4 k^4 γ λ Cos[2 ϕ] + k^4 γ λ^2 Cos[4 ϕ] + 
    4 k^2 (k^2 + Er γ σ) Sin[2 ϕ]^2 Subscript[μ, 1] + 
    4 (k^2 + Er γ σ) (k^2 + tf1 - tf1 Cos[2 ϕ]) Subscript[μ, 2]);
coeffs = Reverse@CoefficientList[eq, σ];
sol = σ /. Solve[FromDigits[Array[#[] &, Length[coeffs], 1],
 σ] == 0, σ] /. n_Integer[] :> coeffs[[n]];
Series[sol[[1]], {k, 0, 2}]
```

Instead of putting `eq` in `Solve`, I put a polynomial with dummy variables (`1[]`, `2[]`, etc.) and then replaced the dummies with the corresponding coefficients in `eq`.

It seems that this method takes about 3 seconds on my computer when I first ran it; 0.03 seconds for subsequent iterations.

The bottom 3 lines (from `coeffs =` to the end of code) should work for any equation `eq`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you method really works fast on my laptop! Can you briefly explain, why? But this thing definitely works for me. I will accept your answer it 2 days.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. The reason I didn't figure it out by myself, is because I thought, that `Solve[eq==0,s]` works like this. It seems that @bbgodfrey has a new version, which is doing it by default. (He wrote, that his mathematica is solving it very fast). I assume, that you too have an older version of Mathematica, like I do. My is 10.0.1.0

Comment: Nice but might be overly complicated. To see what I mean, compare constant terms with what you get from `Solve[(eq /. k -> 0) == 0, \[Sigma]]`. Much smaller and in agreement with the larger result after some random substitution.

Answer (score 2):

I would go about this differently. You have, in effect, a curve parametrized by `sigma` and `k` (regard the other parameters as fixed for the moment). This curve is the zero set for `eq`. You are interested in expanding `sigma` as a series in `k`, around `k=0`. This can be done by setting up equations for derivatives of `sigma` regarded explicitly as a function of `k`; these equations arise from differentiating the original one. As we are evaluating derivatives at `k=0` we can make that substitution after differentiating but before solving. Here is the process.

```
eq = Er k^2 γ ξ (1 + λ Cos[
        2 ϕ]) (3 I k Cos[ϕ] + 4 σ Cos[2 ϕ] + 
      I k Cos[3 ϕ]) Subscript[α, 
     ac] + (ξ + σ) (σ + I k Cos[ϕ]) (8 k^4 + 
      16 k^2 tf1 + 2 k^4 γ + k^4 γ λ^2 + 
      8 Er k^2 γ σ + 16 Er tf1 γ σ + 
      4 k^4 γ λ Cos[2 ϕ] + 
      k^4 γ λ^2 Cos[4 ϕ] + 
      4 k^2 (k^2 + Er γ σ) Sin[
         2 ϕ]^2 Subscript[μ, 1] + 
      4 (k^2 + Er γ σ) (k^2 + tf1 - 
         tf1 Cos[2 ϕ]) Subscript[μ, 2]);
eqk = eq /. σ -> σ[k];
derivsys = Table[D[eqk, {k, j}], {j, 0, 3}];
derivvars = Table[D[σ[k], {k, j}], {j, 0, 3}];
newvars = Array[d, 4, 0];
subs = Thread[derivvars -> newvars];
sys = (derivsys /. subs) /. k -> 0;
soln = Solve[sys == 0, newvars];

During evaluation of In[425]:= Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables. >>

In[436]:= Most[newvars].(k^Range[0, 2]/Factorial[Range[0, 2]]) /. soln

(* Out[436]= {(k^2 Sec[ϕ] (16 tf1 Cos[ϕ] + 
      3 Er γ Cos[ϕ] Subscript[α, ac] + 
      3 Er γ λ Cos[ϕ] Cos[
        2 ϕ] Subscript[α, ac] + 
      Er γ Cos[3 ϕ] Subscript[α, ac] + 
      Er γ λ Cos[2 ϕ] Cos[
        3 ϕ] Subscript[α, ac] + 
      4 tf1 Cos[ϕ] Subscript[μ, 2] - 
      4 tf1 Cos[ϕ] Cos[2 ϕ] Subscript[μ, 
       2]))/(4 Er tf1 γ (-4 - Subscript[μ, 2] + 
      Cos[2 ϕ] Subscript[μ, 2])), -I k Cos[ϕ] + (
  k^2 (1 + λ Cos[2 ϕ]) (-3 Cos[ϕ] + 
     4 Cos[ϕ] Cos[2 ϕ] - 
     Cos[3 ϕ]) Sec[ϕ] Subscript[α, ac])/(
  4 tf1 (-4 - Subscript[μ, 2] + 
     Cos[2 ϕ] Subscript[μ, 2])), -ξ - (
  k^2 Cos[2 ϕ] (1 + λ Cos[2 ϕ]) Subscript[α, 
   ac])/(tf1 (-4 - Subscript[μ, 2] + 
     Cos[2 ϕ] Subscript[μ, 2]))} *)
```

Astute readers will notice there was a wrinkle. Due to multiplicity and/or factors of `sigma` in the reduced derivative equations (by reduced I mean with the `k->0` substitution), we get underdetermined systems. A way around this is to take more derivatives than we actually need, enough to get solutions for the lower derivatives that we require in the expansion. Above I used one extra derivative. I'm sure there is a theory behind this need for extra derivatives (some aspect of prolongation, maybe) but I do not know the details at all.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting method. Your code seems to be incorrect:  my result is different. You never use variable `derivs`

Comment: (1) Thanks for spotting that mistake. I had some earlier definitions and decided to change notation; what got posted was a bit of a mixture. I believe I have corrected it now.

Comment: (2) It is possible that the solution sets are equivalent. One way to check is to substitute values in for most or all parameters (other than `k` of course) and see if the sets of three numeric series agree.

Comment: I checked it against direct method. Solution are equivalent, as should be. I also got the results really fast for 4th order equation, which is not the case for direct method. You helped me a lot.

Comment: I still accepted other answer. Even though your answer is usefull, the other one directly answers my question, whether yours is more workaround. Thanks again

Comment: I have no complaint with the choice of answer that was accepted (I might have accepted it myself). I will remark, though, that the method I showed is hardly a workaround. It is a fairly standard (and useful) way to simplify computations that arise at a particular point in a parameter space.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the new in M12 function [`AsymptoticSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticSolve) for this:$\unicode{958}$

```
eq = Er k^2 γ ξ (1 + λ Cos[2 ϕ]) (3 I k Cos[ϕ] + 4 σ Cos[2 ϕ] + 
I k Cos[3 ϕ]) Subscript[α, ac] + (ξ + σ) (σ + I k Cos[ϕ]) (8 k^4 + 
16 k^2 tf1 + 2 k^4 γ + k^4 γ λ^2 + 8 Er k^2 γ σ + 16 Er tf1 γ σ + 
4 k^4 γ λ Cos[2 ϕ] + k^4 γ λ^2 Cos[4 ϕ] + 
4 k^2 (k^2 + Er γ σ) Sin[2 ϕ]^2 Subscript[μ, 1] + 
4 (k^2 + Er γ σ) (k^2 + tf1 - tf1 Cos[2 ϕ]) Subscript[μ, 2]);

AsymptoticSolve[eq == 0, σ, {k, 0, 2}] //TeXForm
```

> $\left\{\left\{\sigma \to \frac{k^2 \left(3 \gamma  \operatorname{Er} \lambda  \alpha
>    _{\operatorname{ac}} \cos (2 \phi )+\gamma  \operatorname{Er} \lambda  \alpha
>    _{\operatorname{ac}} \cos (2 \phi ) \cos (3 \phi ) \sec (\phi )+\gamma  \operatorname{Er}
>    \alpha _{\operatorname{ac}} \cos (3 \phi ) \sec (\phi )+3 \gamma  \operatorname{Er} \alpha
>    _{\operatorname{ac}}-4 \mu _2 \operatorname{tf1} \cos (2 \phi )+4 \mu _2
>    \operatorname{tf1}+16 \operatorname{tf1}\right)}{4 \gamma  \operatorname{Er}
>    \operatorname{tf1} \left(\mu _2 \cos (2 \phi )-\mu _2-4\right)}\right\},\left\{\sigma \to
>    \frac{k^2 \left(4 \lambda  \alpha _{\operatorname{ac}} \cos ^2(2 \phi )-3 \lambda  \alpha
>    _{\operatorname{ac}} \cos (2 \phi )-\lambda  \alpha _{\operatorname{ac}} \cos (3 \phi )
>    \cos (2 \phi ) \sec (\phi )+4 \alpha _{\operatorname{ac}} \cos (2 \phi )-\alpha
>    _{\operatorname{ac}} \cos (3 \phi ) \sec (\phi )-3 \alpha _{\operatorname{ac}}\right)}{4
>    \operatorname{tf1} \left(\mu _2 \cos (2 \phi )-\mu _2-4\right)}-i k \cos (\phi
>    )\right\},\left\{\sigma \to \frac{k^2 \left(-\lambda  \alpha _{\operatorname{ac}} \cos ^2(2
>    \phi )-\alpha _{\operatorname{ac}} \cos (2 \phi )\right)}{\operatorname{tf1} \left(\mu _2
>    \cos (2 \phi )-\mu _2-4\right)}-\xi \right\}\right\}$

I tested this result against JungHwan's result for some random values of the parameters, and they agree. The above output is much more concise than JungHwan's results.

*Update*

Until you have M12, you can use [`CloudEvaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CloudEvaluate):

```
$Version
CloudEvaluate[System`AsymptoticSolve[eq==0, σ, {k, 0, 2}]] //TeXForm
```

> "11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 6, 2018)"
>
> $\left\{\left\{\sigma \to \frac{k^2 \left(3 \gamma  \operatorname{Er} \lambda  \alpha
>    _{\operatorname{ac}} \cos (2 \phi )+\gamma  \operatorname{Er} \lambda  \alpha
>    _{\operatorname{ac}} \cos (2 \phi ) \cos (3 \phi ) \sec (\phi )+\gamma  \operatorname{Er}
>    \alpha _{\operatorname{ac}} \cos (3 \phi ) \sec (\phi )+3 \gamma  \operatorname{Er} \alpha
>    _{\operatorname{ac}}-4 \mu _2 \operatorname{tf1} \cos (2 \phi )+4 \mu _2
>    \operatorname{tf1}+16 \operatorname{tf1}\right)}{4 \gamma  \operatorname{Er}
>    \operatorname{tf1} \left(\mu _2 \cos (2 \phi )-\mu _2-4\right)}\right\},\left\{\sigma \to
>    \frac{k^2 \left(4 \lambda  \alpha _{\operatorname{ac}} \cos ^2(2 \phi )-3 \lambda  \alpha
>    _{\operatorname{ac}} \cos (2 \phi )-\lambda  \alpha _{\operatorname{ac}} \cos (3 \phi )
>    \cos (2 \phi ) \sec (\phi )+4 \alpha _{\operatorname{ac}} \cos (2 \phi )-\alpha
>    _{\operatorname{ac}} \cos (3 \phi ) \sec (\phi )-3 \alpha _{\operatorname{ac}}\right)}{4
>    \operatorname{tf1} \left(\mu _2 \cos (2 \phi )-\mu _2-4\right)}-i k \cos (\phi
>    )\right\},\left\{\sigma \to \frac{k^2 \left(-\lambda  \alpha _{\operatorname{ac}} \cos ^2(2
>    \phi )-\alpha _{\operatorname{ac}} \cos (2 \phi )\right)}{\operatorname{tf1} \left(\mu _2
>    \cos (2 \phi )-\mu _2-4\right)}-\xi \right\}\right\}$